# backbone.js common event triggered for every view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and have been tasked with extending and maintaining a backbone application.

I'm having an issue with a 'log out' button firing for every view loaded. I have created a base class for common view events:

```
BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    logout: function() {
        console.log('logout');
    },
    events: {
        'click .logout':'logout'
    }
})
```

I then inherit this in the relevant views

```
DashboardView = BaseView.extend({
    el : '#app',
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( _.template($('#Dashboard').html()) );
        return this;
    }
})
```

The templates that are used have the button in
    `<div class="logout"></div>`

There are four views making up the section of the site I'm working on and if all four views have been loaded, the logout fires 4 times when clicked.

I've tried several things to solve this, such as unbinding the view when they change and setElement without success.

Firstly, is this an issue I should solve? If so, how do I go about it?

Cheers

Comment: how do you set the `el` protperty of the view?

Comment: Or more generally, how do you render these 4 views?  Can you post your `render()` methods?

Comment: I've updated the example to include `el` and the render function, the render functions are the same but load a different template. Cheers

Comment: It's not clear to me, why would you put 4 logout buttons in one interface?

Comment: the reason - all your views has one el: '#app'

Comment: fix it and show your code, and it on jsbin

Comment: @KimGysen the logout button is common functionality across the interface. I've attempted to split it out, hence the base class. I've also tried moving it to it's own template and loading it in via the render. But that hasn't changed it's behaviour

Comment: @VasilVanchuk isn't that the point of SPA's to load all the views into the application div? There are other interface elements loaded into other parts of the templates

Comment: Do you have 4 buttons in your intrface? According your code - the only reason for firering 4 events - bind 4 entities on one DOM element

Comment: some like this http://jsbin.com/foxuwopuma/1/ ?

Comment: something like that, but there are 4 templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution.

in the event functions I'm now calling `this.undelegateEvents();` eg:

```
showview : function() {
    this.undelegateEvents();
    app.appRouter.navigate("/dashboard", true);
}
```

and in the app.js in the appRouter function I call `this.DashboardView.delegateEvents();` so:

```
app.appRouter.on('route:dashboard', function(){
    app.dashboard = new DashboardView();
    app.dashboard.render();
    app.dashboard.delegateEvents();
)}
```

I would be interest to know if there are any issues with this solution.

Regards

Comment: im about to post the answer, good that you found out :) it is correct, before route, undelegate the events. By the way, you dont have to call `delegateEvents` as it is already called during initialize

Answer (score 0):

Backbone uses jquery's `on` to register DOM events.
When you instantiate 4 views, 4 event listeners will be bound to the same element if they all have the same parent element defined.

Personally, I tend to create a redirection, using `window.location.href`, if I'm currently in a page that requires authentication. If I'm in a page that does not require authentication, I just re-render the header, replacing the username with the login (/register) button.